# How to get how many posts on a category and display it on wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a "real estate sale campaign", you can check it [here](http://www.onecia.com.br/oneoff). I've created a loop for each apartment/house on WordPress, I've made a page theme. On the page, you can check that I have a "neighborhood" section, where I want to display how many apartments I have in each "category", like Bela Vista, Boa Vista and others.

The problem is that I don't know how to do that. Here is the code I use to loop the apartments when the fields are filled:

```
<?php
$newsArgs = array( 
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    "orderby" => 'meta_value_num',
    "meta_key" => 'numerooff',
    "order" => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property-status',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'oneoff',
         )
    )                                                           
);

$newsLoop = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );                  
while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post();?>
```

Maybe I should copy something of this code, to display the numbers? I don't know really. [Here](http://prntscr.com/hihd9l) is where I create the slug I'm trying to use. On the snippet above, you can see where I want to place it:

```
<!--  |-----------BELA VISTA-------------|   -->
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
    <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/oneoff-belavista" target="_blank" class="">
    <div class="view efffect">
        <div class="portfolio-image">

            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/acoes/oneoff/bairro/belavista.jpg" alt=""></div> 
            <div class="mask text-center">
                <h3 style="font-family: 'Novecento Wide Light'; color: #fff;">Bela Vista</h3>
                <h4 style="color: #fff;">I WANT TO DISPLAY IT HERE</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></a>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_term() and get_category() functions return an object which has count value.

So you can use such script:

```
<?php
$cat_by_id=get_term(TERM_ID_HERE); // get_category(CAT_ID_HERE)
//$cat_by_slug= get_term_by('slug', 'oneoff-belavista', 'property-status'); 
?> 
<h4 style="color: #fff;"><?php echo $cat_by_id->count;?></h4>
```

Comment: It didn't work, but i'm still trying... It shows nothing on the page. Could i get the slug, you think?

Comment: what did you write instead of "TERM_ID_HERE" ?

Comment: I've tested on neigborhood "Bela Vista", and wrote "oneoff-belavista". See the term on wordpress here: http://prntscr.com/hijjss   See the code here: http://prntscr.com/hijkff    As you can see, it's a taxonomy. Maybe i should do a different call?

Comment: Still no sucess... I've done what you said: http://prntscr.com/hijr2x  but it still don't show the number of pages on that category. I really apreciate your help. Please, do you have any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: get_term_by() function can accept slug as well.(but you have to add taxonomy name there) But get_term requires ID parameter. So instead of using get_term("string") you should use get_term(NUMBER_HERE). You can easily get that category's ID from wp-admin

Comment: Taxonomy custom name is "property-status", and my slug is "oneoff-belavista". I was trying to use "get_term_by()", but it requires $value and i didn't know what to fill. This was my last try, who was not suceeeded.  <?php  $term = get_term_by('oneoff-belavista', '$value', 'property-status'); ?>

Comment: $term = get_term_by('slug', 'oneoff-belavista', 'property-status');

Comment: IT WORKED! My god, thanks really much, i'm really happy! One million thanks to you!

I'll look forward to my next challenge: Make a "load on scroll" function. If you know something about it, could ou please help me? topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620250/how-to-show-more-content-on-scroll-wordpress-theme?noredirect=1#comment82198690_47620250

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to get posts count is to use [found_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/found_posts) hook:

```
<h4 style="color: #fff;"><?php echo $newsLoop->found_posts; ?></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `$newsLoop = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );` use `$count=$newsLoop->found_posts; echo $count;`